# How to make multiple projects within one solution in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution called `book_example` with one project inside called `first_project`.  I want to make several more example projects called `second_project`, `third_project` etc. within this solution.

So, when I open `book_example` in the solution explorer it would show all of my projects.  I want them to share source code so all file paths etc. should be the same.

When I right click the solution `Add -> New Project` even if I use a template that is exactly the same as my existing `first_project` all of the paths do not work.  Basic things like my `source.cpp` say "This file does not exist or has been moved".

**Edit:** To be more clear, when I try a solution like the one proposed by madocter below, I get errors with the project. I.e.:

[image: Error]

What is the correct way to create several projects within one solution that share code?

Comment: Includes and such are per-project settings now where they used to be global. I have not done it recently, but you used to be able to make a property sheet and include it in each project to setup common things. To include the same source files you need to drag them to each project. You might consider a library for the common code.